# jquery UI date time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using this jquery ui date time picker http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

For two date time pickers where the first one gets the `From` date (the start of a date range) and the other gets the `to` date (the end of a date range). Code example Below:

```
var getTimeLapseFromTimestamp= $('#from');
getTimeLapseFromTimestamp.datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
    stepHour: 1,
    stepMinute: 10,
    stepSecond: 10,
    showSecond: false,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    onSelect: function(date) {

    },
    numberOfMonths: 1
});
```

and

```
var getTimeLapseToTimestamp = $('#to');
getTimeLapseToTimestamp .datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
    stepHour: 1,
    stepMinute: 10,
    stepSecond: 10,
    showSecond: false,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    onSelect: function(date) {

    },
    numberOfMonths: 1
});
```

What I would like is to that when a date is selected in the `From` datetime picker, the maxDate and MinDate properties of the `To` datetime picker are adjusted using the onSelect function so that the user cannot select a date range more than 3 months of the `From` timestamp. Anyone with some ideas, i have had trouble with this sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the following in your onselect key,

```
$('#date').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(startDate.getMonth() + 3));
```

Comment: Thanks for this, added it with a duplicate post ;)